# Monitor when an Azure Function has scaled

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Im sure I saw something online about this but I now can't find it anywhere

I want to show the power of Azure functions and how they scale automatically

Is there a log or event or something that I can use to show when a new instance of a function has been spun up due to high load

Has anyone got a good scenario that they have used to demonstrate this in action?

Paul

Comment: If you connect the Function to Application Insights and look at the "Live Metrics" blade, there is a Servers list at the bottom. I've not tried but this might show the list of instances expand and contract during scaling if you watched.

Comment: @NoahStahl : You are correct. We can actually see the number increase and decrease. But this is only when you are observing the app Live. If you need to see how the app scaled some time ago, as Rimaz mentioned, we need to enable the scale controller logs.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure scale controller logs for azure functions to understand when azure functions spins up/down a new/existing instance, the reason for doing so, as well as the previous and current instance counts

See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-scale-controller-logs

and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/analyze-telemetry-data#query-scale-controller-logs